# Virtual linux drive on a NAS - recommendations

Tags: linux, storage, network-attached-storage, ntfs, truecrypt

I have a Linux server currently running under a Microsoft Virtual Machine.  I have it set up so that the storage drive is set up as a secondary virtual disk.  I need to move this machine to a new box running LXC, but storage is tight.  I'd like to use my NAS for the storage drive, but it is currently formatted as NTFS for a number of other applications in my environment, so I can't link a folder to the NAS and keep the necessary permissions to run my Linux-based application.

I've thought about using TrueCrypt to create a virtual drive that is stored on the NAS, then mounting that under my Linux VM.  Would this be a valid method to use, or am I asking for trouble.

Also, would using a loop device stored on the NAS be a better option?

Recommendations are very welcome.

Comment: Does "storage drive is set up as a secondary virtual disk" means that you have attached the Host's physical drive to the Guest Linux?
If yes, then you must be on an NTFS drive now. If no, then you have your virtual storage as a file on the Host. Or I didn't get the problem clear enough :-)

Comment: the secondary virtual disk is a MS VHD file sitting on the SAN.

Comment: A SAN doesn't store files, it stores blocks. Well, actually, a SAN is a switch that is used to move blocks of data around with the scsi protocol, but either way, you're mis-using this term. You have a NAS is there's a file on it.

Comment: my mistake...being a little dyslexic this morning.